# using connection manager with orm cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.x

Every tutorial or documentation regarding this subject is used with sql queries but never with new orm.
I have two data sources defined in config/app.php: default and not_default
with same tables and columns, when the user login the default database is connected.
when the user clicks a certain button i need to change the connected database to not_default:

I achieved this so far:

```
ConnectionManager::get('default')->disconnect();
ConnectionManager::get('not_default')->connect();
ConnectionManager::get('not_default')->begin();  //dont know if required
```

when doing this: `echo ConnectionManager::get('not_default')->isConnected();` I get 1 for not_default and 0 for default so it is connected 
but the problem is when getting the model's TableRegistry the connectionname is still the default one!! How to change it???

I want to be able to get data using orm from database other than the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConnectionManager::alias()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_alias).

Connection aliases allow you to rename active connections without overwriting the aliased connection.

```
ConnectionManager::alias('not_default','default');
//from now on, all calls to default will resolve to not_default datasource
```